# Google Python Image Library - How to resize an image based on its width?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, image-manipulation

I have this code to make a resize of an uploaded image as a thumbnail.

```
project.thumbnail = db.Blob(images.resize(self.request.get("img"),188,96))
```

However, it does not do what I want. It always resize the image to have the fixed height of 96.

Instead, I want to have all the resized images to have the same width of 188.

What should I do?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call this as `images.resize(data, width=188)`

Comment: So the documentation from Google must be missing something :D

http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass.html#Image_resize